# Django: is it possible to exclude ForeignKey in derived model

Tags: django, django-models

i have this model

```
class Base(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

above model is inherited in following model:

```
class Profile(Base):
     email = models.TextField()
     sent = models.BooleanField()
```

`Profile` has `user` , a ForeignKey, which is not required here

Is that possible to get away with `user`field in `Profile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is explicitly not supported, as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) explains.